# Nautilus no longer finds LAN computers - shows Windows Network and "Folder is Empty"

Tags: nautilus

Have been using Nautilus in Ubuntu 18.04 to browse shared LAN Win7 directories without difficulty until a ubuntu update this week changed my Nautilus access to the LAN.  It now shows Windows Network instead of the LAN computers, and gives "Folder is Empty" when I try to access the LAN.

I can access Other Locations by searching smb://, but this is quite cumbersome.  I don't know all their ips.

My smb.conf hasn't changed:

- workgroup is correct.
- client max protocol = NT1.

I didn't initiate the update.  It was initiated by my operating system.  What could have changed that would eliminate my ready access to 20 other computers on the network?

Comment: I'm actually now thinking that the problem wasn't from a Ubuntu update, but rather from a patch Tuesday Windows update.  I'm thinking that the Windows update has disabled SMBv1 for security purposes, removing my ability to connect.

Comment: Not a Windows update issue.  I started an XP computer on the LAN and it's shared drives no longer show in Nautilus unless I smb://ip.  So what in the world just happened that my 4 Ubuntu computers stopped having Nautilus access to the 20 Win7 computers on my LAN?